# How To Install Virtualbox Guest Additions On CentOS via Command Line only

Tags: centos, virtualbox

Reading the Virtualbox user manual, I finally got [[here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp11259744)], which explains how to install Virtualbox Guest Additions on a Linux guest via Command Line.

But it's not clear enough for me (I just started learning some commands). Can someone put down the exact commands you would use to install Virtualbox Guest Additions via CLI? (which includes finding where virtualbox guest additions has been mounted etc.)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

... finally this worked for me, should also work for anybody else trying to install VirtualBox Guest Additions on a CentOS (x86_64) virtual server in command line mode.

```
# yum update
# yum install dkms gcc make kernel-devel bzip2 binutils patch libgomp glibc-headers glibc-devel kernel-headers elfutils-libelf-devel
# mkdir -p /media/cdrom
# mount /dev/scd0 /media/cdrom
# sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Note:
In CentOS 7 and higher the cdrom is at `/dev/sr0` instead of `/dev/scd0`.

When the process is complete, reboot the system. That's all.

Comment: I do not think there is a need for the reboot here. Just check the vbox* modules are installed under /lib and then run modprobe for each vbox module; make sure the vbox startup scripts at /etc/init.d/vbox* are all (re)started. To just check whether the VBoxAdditions are working, I would start with testing the copy-paste between the source and vmguest. Run VBoxClient-all command and see if it returns anything. If nothing is returned VBox is setup fine. Also, check chkconfig to make sure the vbox startup scripts are properly defined to start at required runlevels.

Comment: You need to `yum install make` as well

Comment: I try to do the line mount /dev/scd0 /media/cdrom and I get: mount point /media/cdrom does not exist. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Please also note that you must add your username to the groups: vboxsf, vboxusers (first create this one).

Comment: @theJerm Check this one: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/development (under section: **VirtualBox Guest Additions**)

Comment: @theJerm I hope you already figured this out, but for the record: create the mountpoint (just a directory) with `sudo mkdir /media/cdrom`.

Comment: Need `yum install dkms` too.  Was getting no output at all when running `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`.

Comment: On a minimal install of CentOS 6.4 64b the install command was `sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`. I also had to install Perl (`yum install perl`) and create the mount-point (`sudo mkdir -p /media/cdrom`).

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it asks for linux headers.

Comment: In CentOS 7 the cdrom is not at `/dev/scd0` but instead at `/dev/sr0`

Comment: In case people are wondering... before any of this is done, you have to use _Insert Guest Additions CD image_, (currently found in _Devices_ in the virtualbox's window menu), in order for `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` to be actually available.

Comment: In addition to this, I had to do `sudo yum install kernel-headers` and when executing the install, `KERN_DIR=/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64 sudo /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`. `EXPORT`ing the `KERN_DIR` did not work. But alas, I was able to install this. :/

Comment: If you can't mount the CD for some reason (eg: you're working over `ssh`), you can download an `ISO` of the guest additions for any version from `http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox`

Comment: If you need to keep your guest additions in sync when using `vagrant`, check out the [vagrant-vbguest](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) plugin.

Comment: in addition to jxmallet comment, if you can't mount the CD, then you can download the the ISO with `wget` e.g. `wget https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.18/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.2.18.iso` (but choose the right version number) and then mount the iso with `mount -t iso9660 -o loop VBoxGuestAdditions_5.2.18.iso /mnt/cdrom`

Comment: make sure you reboot after the yum update command. And remove the older kernel-devel package.

Comment: But why bother at all since paste into linux console does not seem to work anyway.

Answer (score 16):

@its_me's answer *almost* worked, but it failed building some kernel modules.

If it doesn't work for you, look at the messages.

In my case, one of them asked to look into `/var/log/vboxadd-install.log`. There it said something about missing kernel sources and to provide the kernel source directory with e.g. `KERN_DIR=/path/to/kernel/sources`.

Since `kernel-devel` and sources at `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64` were already installed, I was confused, but called it with the requested environment variable

```
KERN_DIR=/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64 sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Now it complained about missing header files and suggested to do

```
yum install kernel-devel-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64
```

As you can see, this is a slightly different version, `504.16.2` vs just `504`. After installing the proper `kernel-devel` package, building and then installing worked as expected.

---

So, running kernel and installed kernel sources (aka `kernel-devel`) must match. You can verify this by looking at the running kernel with

```
uname -a
```

and the installed sources at

```
ls /usr/src/kernels
```

---

As a final conclusion, whatever happens, look at the messages and log files provided.

Comment: I made the kernel sources match the kernel, by updating the kernel. yum update kernel.

Comment: If it is not matching and you just updated the kernel -> reboot to match (if you can).

Answer (score 6):

This is an old thread but came up in my search for a similar issue.  In case anyone else runs into this, the following answer solved it for me:

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Note* The URL says 2010 but the article was updated in 2013.

Comment: These steps are a lot better, because they include all of the necessary prerequisites like perl and dkms

Answer (score 4):

I'm posting an updated answer, as because I needed to perform a few additional steps to install. I'm using VirtualBox 5.0.14r105127. Each command will have to be prepended with "sudo".

```
yum update
yum install gcc
yum install kernel-devel
yum install bzip2
yum install kernel-devel-2.6.32-573.el6.i686
mkdir /media/cdrom
mount /dev/scd0 /media/cdrom
sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Also, I got a "FAILED" message for the OpenGL support module, but this can be ignored on a server system.

Answer (score 2):

After installing the VBOXADDITIONS you might need to do this:

```
In VirtualBox click View>>Auto Resize Guest Display (Host + G)
```

because the screen resolution did not work for me until I applied this final configuration to VirtualBox.

Comment: On Centos 7 I still had to install gcc, kernel-devel, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Vagrant for scripting your VirtualBox, you can simply install the vb-guest plugin. The source code for the same can be found here https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest/tree/master/lib/vagrant-vbguest.

Some hints can be gleamed from the source code here to automate this process.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

`yum update`

Step 2:

Go to `Device-> Install Guest Additions CD Image -> Next`

Then provide the root password . That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little detail ... I had a CentOS 6.6 minimal, did all the  "yum update" and "yum install" but I was still stuck until I've read this in Olaf's response

> ... this is a slightly different version, 504.16.2 vs just 504. After installing the proper kernel-devel package, building and then installing worked as expected.
>
> So, running kernel and installed kernel sources (aka kernel-devel) must match.

checking on my install I had the same problem, after doing a reboot, everything was ok. The machine was still running with the old kernel.
After this the next problem as that perl was missing so I had to do also an

```
yum install perl
```