# Install Guest Additions CentOS 64 (guest), Win 8 (host)

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I am attempting to Install Guest Additions CentOS 64 (guest), Win 8 (host) Oracle's VM Virtual Box quite unsuccessfully. I have tried to follow the method answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18435/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-centos-via-command-line-only).  But, I get the "mount point /media/cdrom does not exist" issue also mentioned in the same post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mount point is just a directory, you can create it (as root) with:

```
mkdir /media/cdrom
```